# Share Button: wrong meta data when published on FB

Tags: facebook, button, share, meta

Problem: when someone uses the Share button from my blog, it publishes on their page this way:

[Name of sharer] of Seattle shared a link via [Wrong Name].

The name that comes after "via" is the name of a guy who used to be a developer on the blog six months ago. Nowhere is his name in any setting anywhere on my blog, or in any code I could find.

What value determines the name that displays there? Referrer? Description? I can't find the answer to that, or where to edit them.

Been using Facebook Share button on my Wordpress blog via plugin Social Sharing Toolkit ( http://www.active-bits.nl/support/social-sharing-toolkit/ ) for over a week.

Here's the code from the plugin (note: it includes options for "Like" and "Follow" buttons):

```
<?php
class MR_Social_Sharing_Toolkit_Facebook extends MR_Social_Sharing_Toolkit_Button {
function __construct() {
    $this->share_buttons[] = array('name' => 'fb_like', 'title' => 'Facebook Like', 'types' => array('none', 'none_text', 'horizontal', 'vertical'));
    $this->share_buttons[] = array('name' => 'fb_share', 'title' => 'Facebook Share', 'types' => array('none', 'horizontal', 'vertical', 'icon_small', 'icon_small_text', 'icon_medium', 'icon_medium_text', 'icon_large'));
    $this->share_buttons[] = array('name' => 'fb_send', 'title' => 'Facebook Send', 'types' => array('none'));
    $this->follow_buttons[] = array('name' => 'follow_facebook', 'title' => 'Facebook', 'id' => 'id:', 'types' => array('icon_small', 'icon_small_text', 'icon_medium', 'icon_medium_text', 'icon_large'));
    $this->title = 'Facebook';
    $this->icon = 'facebook';
}

function fb_like($url, $title, $type, $id, $media = '', $description = '', $text = '', $icon = '') {
    //$retval = '<iframe src="https://www.facebook.com/plugins/like.php?locale='.__('en_US','mr_social_sharing_toolkit').'&amp;href='.urlencode($url).'&amp;layout=';
    $retval = '<div class="fb-like" data-href="'.$url.'" data-send="false" ';
    switch ($type) {
        case 'horizontal':
            //$retval .= 'button_count';
            if ($id == 'recommend') {
                $width = __('fb_horizontal_recommend_width','mr_social_sharing_toolkit');
                $width = ($width == 'fb_horizontal_recommend_width') ? '120' : $width;
                $retval .= 'data-layout="button_count" data-width="'.$width.'" data-action="recommend"';                    
            } else {
                $width = __('fb_horizontal_width','mr_social_sharing_toolkit');
                $width = ($width == 'fb_horizontal_width') ? '90' : $width;
                $retval .= 'data-layout="button_count" data-width="'.$width.'"';                    
            }
            $height = '21';             
            break;
        case 'vertical':
            //$retval .= 'box_count';
            if ($id == 'recommend') {
                $width = __('fb_vertical_recommend_width','mr_social_sharing_toolkit');
                $width = ($width == 'fb_vertical_recommend_width') ? '92' : $width;
                $retval .= 'data-layout="box_count" data-width="'.$width.'" data-action="recommend"';                   
            } else {
                $width = __('fb_vertical_width','mr_social_sharing_toolkit');
                $width = ($width == 'fb_vertical_width') ? '55' : $width;
                $retval .= 'data-layout="box_count" data-width="'.$width.'"';                   
            }
            $height = '62';
            break;
        case 'none_text':
            //$retval .= 'standard';
            if ($id == 'recommend') {
                $width = 'auto';
                $retval .= 'data-width="'.$width.'" data-action="recommend"';                   
            } else {
                $width = 'auto';
                $retval .= 'data-width="'.$width.'"';                   
            }
            $height = '25';
            break;
        default:
            //$retval .= 'standard';
            if ($id == 'recommend') {
                $width = __('fb_standard_recommend_width','mr_social_sharing_toolkit');
                $width = ($width == 'fb_standard_standard_recommend_width') ? '91' : $width;
                $retval .= 'data-width="'.$width.'" data-action="recommend"';                   
            } else {
                $width = __('fb_standard_width','mr_social_sharing_toolkit');
                $width = ($width == 'fb_standard_width') ? '51' : $width;
                $retval .= 'data-width="'.$width.'"';                   
            }
            $height = '24';
            break;
    }
    //$retval .= '&amp;show_faces=false&amp;width='.$width.'&amp;height='.$height.'" scrolling="no" frameborder="0" style="border:none; overflow:hidden; width:'.$width.'px; height:'.$height.'px;" allowTransparency="true"></iframe>';*/
    $retval .= ' data-show-faces="false"></div>';
    $lang = __('en_US','mr_social_sharing_toolkit');
    $footer = (get_option('mr_social_sharing_js_footer') == 1) ? true : false;
    $this->enqueue_script('Social_sharing_facebook_root', plugins_url('/button.facebook.js', __FILE__), $footer);
    $this->enqueue_script('Social_sharing_facebook_xfbml', 'http://connect.facebook.net/'.$lang.'/all.js#xfbml=1', $footer);
    return '<span style="display: inline-block; width: '.$width.'px; height: '.$height.'px; overflow: hidden;">'.$retval.'</span>';
}

function fb_share($url, $title, $type, $id, $media = '', $description = '', $text = '', $icon = '') {   
    switch ($type) {
        case 'vertical':
            $retval = '<fb:share-button type="box_count" href="'.$url.'"></fb:share-button>';
            //$retval = '<a name="fb_share" type="box_count" share_url="'.$url.'" href="http://www.facebook.com/sharer.php">Share</a>';
            $this->enqueue_script('Social_sharing_facebook_root', plugins_url('/button.facebook.js', __FILE__));
            $footer = (get_option('mr_social_sharing_js_footer') == 1) ? true : false;
            $this->enqueue_script('Social_sharing_facebook_xfbml', 'http://connect.facebook.net/en_US/all.js#xfbml=1', $footer);
            //$this->enqueue_script('Social_sharing_facebook_share', 'http://static.ak.fbcdn.net/connect.php/js/FB.Share', $footer);
            break;
        case 'horizontal':
            $retval = '<fb:share-button type="button_count" href="'.$url.'"></fb:share-button>';
            //$retval = '<a name="fb_share" type="button_count" share_url="'.$url.'" href="http://www.facebook.com/sharer.php">Share</a>';
            $this->enqueue_script('Social_sharing_facebook_root', plugins_url('/button.facebook.js', __FILE__));
            $footer = (get_option('mr_social_sharing_js_footer') == 1) ? true : false;
            $this->enqueue_script('Social_sharing_facebook_xfbml', 'http://connect.facebook.net/en_US/all.js#xfbml=1', $footer);
            //$this->enqueue_script('Social_sharing_facebook_share', 'http://static.ak.fbcdn.net/connect.php/js/FB.Share', $footer);
            break;
        case 'none':
            $retval = '<fb:share-button type="button" href="'.$url.'"></fb:share-button>';
            //$retval = '<a name="fb_share" type="button" share_url="'.$url.'" href="http://www.facebook.com/sharer.php">Share</a>';
            $this->enqueue_script('Social_sharing_facebook_root', plugins_url('/button.facebook.js', __FILE__));
            $footer = (get_option('mr_social_sharing_js_footer') == 1) ? true : false;
            $this->enqueue_script('Social_sharing_facebook_xfbml', 'http://connect.facebook.net/en_US/all.js#xfbml=1', $footer);
            //$this->enqueue_script('Social_sharing_facebook_share', 'http://static.ak.fbcdn.net/connect.php/js/FB.Share', $footer);
            break;
        default:
            $url = 'https://www.facebook.com/sharer/sharer.php?u='.urlencode($url).'&amp;t='.urlencode($title);
            $text = ($text == '') ? __('Share on','mr_social_sharing_toolkit').' Facebook' : $text;
            $retval = $this->get_icon($type, $url, $text, $icon, true);
            break;
    }
    return $retval;
}

function fb_send($url, $title, $type, $id, $media = '', $description = '', $text = '', $icon = '') {
    //$retval = '<div id="fb-root"></div><fb:send href="'.$url.'" font=""></fb:send>';
    $retval = '<div class="fb-send" data-href="'.$url.'"></div>';
    $lang = __('en_US','mr_social_sharing_toolkit');
    $this->enqueue_script('Social_sharing_facebook_root', plugins_url('/button.facebook.js', __FILE__));
    $footer = (get_option('mr_social_sharing_js_footer') == 1) ? true : false;
    $this->enqueue_script('Social_sharing_facebook_xfbml', 'http://connect.facebook.net/'.$lang.'/all.js#xfbml=1', $footer);
    return $retval;         
}   

function follow_facebook($type, $id, $text = '', $icon = '') {
    $url = 'http://www.facebook.com/'.$id;
    $text = ($text == '') ? __('Friend me on','mr_social_sharing_toolkit').' Facebook' : $text;
    $blank = (get_option('mr_social_sharing_follow_new') == 1) ? true : false;
    return $this->get_icon($type, $url, $text, $icon, false, $blank);
}
```

}
?>

Answer (score 0):

Look for him in the Users section and see what his privileges are. I would delete his account then put your URL in the Facebook Debugger to rescrape your site. See what happens then.

Comment: Yeah I deleted his account yesterday. Could it take time for it to show?

Comment: This is what I got from the debugger:

Inferred Property: The 'og:url' property should be explicitly provided, even if a value can be inferred from other tags.
Inferred Property: The 'og:title' property should be explicitly provided, even if a value can be inferred from other tags.
Inferred Property: The 'og:description' property should be explicitly provided, even if a value can be inferred from other tags.
Inferred Property: The 'og:image' property should be explicitly provided, even if a value can be inferred from other tags.

Comment: How do I provide those...?